# The merge tags in mandrill don't work in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mandrill

I use Mandrill plugin for Codeigniter.

I created HTML template through Mandrill account, named `fess1` with merge tag `FNAME`, after I published it.

Example:

```
 ...
<p>
  <span>Hi *|FNAME|*,<br></span>
</p>
....
```

Now I try to send mail from codeigniter like:

```
 private  function sendMailMandrill($owner_name,$business_name,$owner_email){

        $message = array('dest_mail' => $owner_email);   

        $message['to'] = array(array('email' => 'mim@wefi.com'));

        $mergeVars[] = array(
            'rcpt' => array(array('email' => 'mim@wefi.com')),
            'vars' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'FNAME',
                    'content' => 'Fessy'
                )
            )
        );

        $message['merge'] = true;
        $template_name = 'fess1';        
        $template_content = array(  // I don't know what I need to provide here, left it empty
                                 array(
                                 'name' => 'example name',
                                 'content' => 'example content'
                                 )
                ); 
        $message['merge_vars'] = $mergeVars;       

        return $this->mandrill->messages_send_template($template_name, $template_content, $message);
    }
```

The result:

I get the mail, based on `fess1` template, but with the tag `*|FNAME|*`.

Sounds like Mandrill didn't recognize the merge tag.

I used `mandrill->messages_send_template` but since my template stored into Mandrill account I have no clue what I need to provide for `$template_content`.

So I wrote dummy info there.

Did I miss something?

Thank you,

**[EDIT]**

From logs this is what I send:

```
{
    "template_name": "fess1",
    "template_content": [
        {
            "name": "example name",
            "content": "example content"
        }
    ],
    "message": {
        "owner_name": "עידו",
        "business_name": "פלאפל מוסקו",
        "dest_mail": "maxim@wifi.com",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "maxim@wifi.com"
            }
        ],
        "merge": "true",
        "merge_vars": [
            {
                "rcpt": [
                    {
                        "email": "maxim@wifi.com"
                    }
                ],
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "FNAME",
                        "content": "Fessy"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide blank information for the `template_content` parameter.  That parameter allows you to [use mc:edit regions in your template](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21694286-How-do-I-add-dynamic-content-using-editable-regions-in-my-template-). It is a required parameter, but a blank array will suffice if all of the content is in your template in Mandrill.

As for whether the `merge_vars` were recognized, the first thing we recommend is inspecting the API Logs for your account (Settings > API Logs) since that will show you the JSON that Mandrill received.  You can then compare that to the expected JSON format from the Mandrill API docs: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-template

It looks like your arrays may not be nested as expected. Once you view the JSON that's being generated as compared with the expected format, you can also view the PHP documentation for the Mandrill PHP client. It may not be identical to the CodeIgniter plugin, but should give you an idea of how the `merge_vars` parameter would be structured in PHP: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html

In `mergeVars` you created array instead `key:value`. Change it to:

```
'rcpt' => 'mim@wefi.com',
```

Comment: Great, found the problem with `rcpt`. BTW do you know why I get all the time mail with prefix in title: `[TEST]`.

Comment: Mandrill will append a prefix if you're sending template tests from within the application, but otherwise, it would be something likely being passed from the environment you're in. I'd double check those API logs to see if it's being passed there. If so, then it's being generated before it ever even gets to Mandrill.